# Cosa significa "scollato" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *L'amica geniale* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> All’inizio restavo nascosta dietro un angolo e mi sporgevo per vedere se Lila arrivava. Poi, visto che non si muoveva, mi costringevo a raggiungerla, le passavo le pietre, le tiravo anch’io. Ma lo facevo senza convinzione, ho fatto molte cose nella mia vita ma mai convinta, mi sono sempre sentita un po’ **scollata** dalle mie stesse azioni.

Ho cercato il significato di "scollato" in alcuni dizionari. Tuttavia non riesco a capire il senso di questo termine nel brano precedente. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il significato di *scollata*, qui, è quello del verbo *scollare* (separare due parti prima unite dalla colla, quindi saldamente). Di solito si ritiene che le azioni di una persona siano sempre aderenti (attaccate, incollate) alle sue intenzioni, ai suoi pensieri, e viceversa. In questo caso, la protagonista dice che per lei non era così: spesso compiva azioni che in realtà non desiderava compiere. L'uso della parola, dunque, è figurato e serve a spiegare la psicologia del personaggio.